# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. Failed to execute aapt Ionic 4 android

Tags: android, angular, ionic4

`ionic cordova build android --prod`

This is the error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

> The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the
>   following changes:
>
> Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX)
>   Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following
>   changes in your app:
>
> Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later. Upgrade
>   compileSdkVersion to 28 or later. Update your app to use Jetpack
>   (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX. Firebase
>   Bill of Materials (BoM)

Due to the above android SDK change, I cannot build the APK now. I have tried many solutions. But no luck yet. Any clue here?

***I have tried this. But it is not working:***

*build.gradle*

```
project.ext {
  defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.0" //String
  defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
  defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
  defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}
```

*project.properties*

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/stella-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-annotations:28.+
```

Tried this too. But no luck? i.e. `ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0`

```
$ ionic cordova platform add android@8.0.0
> cordova.cmd platform add android@8.0.0 --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@8.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.tt.la
        Name: la
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-28
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@8.0.0
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Uh oh!
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! This is how I have sorted out my issue. It is working fine now.

**Note:** My problem here was with the ***Firebase plugin***: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

***Solution:***

```
1. ionic cordova platform rm android    

2. ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase

3. ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue 

4. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx

5. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

6. ionic cordova platform add android

7.ionic cordova build android --prod
```

Ref: [Git Issue](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1084#issuecomment-503472455)

Comment: @Pouloulou You can check other solutions here: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/1084#issue-457701624